# How to deploy Laravel project using Remote Desktop Connection and AWS and run the application on {MY_IP}:8000/

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, remote-desktop, ipv4, aws-code-deploy

I had made an EC2 instance on my AWS and also established the connection with RDC in my local system.

Installed my required modules and set up the environment for the Laravel successfully.
Xampp is also installed and the database connection is established
And my project is running perfectly in that RDC system's Localhost on port 8000

[image]

My problem I am not able to run my solution on port 8000 when I am hitting the server with my IP.

[image]

Basically, no port other than port 80 is opening via IP

How can I open my project on port 8000 via my IPv4 or IP?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to this.
Instead of deploying the project on localhost:{my_ip} to deploy it at 0.0.0.0:{my_ip}

In Laravel run this command in the workspace ok the project, it will be reflected on the respective domain as well.

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

`--host` defines the hostname of the project and `port` defines the port on which you are planning to deploy your source.

it solved my problem hope it will help !!!